# Configuration space of flags

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, geometric-invariant-theory, projective-geometry

Let $U\subset \mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$ be the Zariksi open set of ordered quadruple of distinct points in the projective line. The quotient of $U$ by the projective transformation group $PSL(2)$ can be identified to $\mathbb{P}^1$ by cross-ratio.

Motivated by a paper of Fock and Goncharov (arXiv:math/0311149), I want to understand the configuration space of flags.

**Question:** Let $\mathscr{F}$ be the variety of flags in $\mathbb{P}^2$.Let $n\geq 3$. Is there a Zariski open set $U\subset\mathscr{F}^{(n)}$ like above, consisting of $n$ flags "in general position" in some sense, such that the quotient of $PSL(3)$-action on $U$ is a projective variety? And what is the quotient?

For those who know a little geometric invariant theory, I could have just asked "How to describle (semi-)stable points of the $PSL(3)$-action on  $\mathscr{F}^{(n)}$, and what is the quotient?"

Comment: Is U the set of distinct point?

Comment: Yes, I have edited the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many GIT quotients, since to define one requires a choice of $G$-line bundle, so a pair of naturals for each $F$.

There's an obvious democratic choice -- $(a,b) = (1,1)$ for every $F$ -- but I think this will in general lead to properly semistable reduction, which is a little icky. (Instead of just taking the quotient of an open set, further identifications are required.)

I will be lazy and put all the burden on the first three: $(2n,2n), (4n-1,3n), (n,1)$, and $(1,1)$ for each of the rest. I think the effect on the stable set is the following. The first two flags must be in general position w.r.t. one another, so we can use $PGL(3)$ to move them to the base and anti-base flag, respectively. This leaves over the diagonal matrices $T$ acting on $F^{n-2}$. The line in the third flag shouldn't be in the $xy$, $xz$, or $yz$ coordinate planes. That defines an open set in $F$ whose $T$-quotient turns out to be ${\mathbb P}^1$. So the final quotient space is ${\mathbb P}^1 \times F^{n-3}$.

For more about these undemocratic GIT quotients, see the purple book [Guillemin-Lerman-Sternberg].

Answer (score 4):

(This should be a comment but I don't have enough reputation to leave one.)  The quotient of $U$ by $PGL(2)$ is $\mathbb{P}^1 \backslash \{ 0, 1, \infty \}$.  To get something compact, you need to allow the four points to lie on a stable curve -- in this case, you need to allow the union of two $\mathbb{P}^1$'s with two of your points on each component (none of the points coinciding with the node of intersection).

You might want to look at [Multiple Flag Varieties of Finite Type](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9805067) by Magyar, Weyman, and Zelevinsky.  It characterizes the conditions under which you get finitely many $PGL(m)$ orbits on products of (partial) flag varieties and may help give a sense of the complexities involved.

Comment: Thanks, that paper is enlightening, although it treats a different question from mine. 


However, I can't understand your first paragraphe... To me, the quotient is just $\mathbb{P}^1$, no need to remove three points.


And can't image how can stalbe curves be involved

Comment: $PGL(2)$ acts simply transitively on triples of distinct points, so any element of $(\mathbb{P}^1)^4$ can be brought to a unique element of the form $(0, 1, \infty, z)$, where $z$ is any element of $\mathbb{P}^1$ except $0$, $1$, or $\infty$.  The book An Invitation to Quantum Cohomology by Koch and Vainsencher has a very good discussion of this moduli space.

Comment: Ahh, you are right, I made a mistake on crossratios.